# Call Win32 CalculatePopupWindowPosition from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to call the WinAPI function CalculatePopupWindowPosition in C# using P/Invoke. From

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd565861(v=vs.85).aspx

I see that it's syntax is:

```
BOOL WINAPI CalculatePopupWindowPosition(  
  _In_      const POINT *anchorPoint,  
  _In_      const SIZE *windowSize,  
  _In_      UINT flags,  
  _In_opt_  RECT *excludeRect,  
  _Out_     RECT *popupWindowPosition  
);
```

I then tried to import it using the following code in C#

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool CalculatePopupWindowPosition
(
    [In] ref POINT anchorPoint,
    [In] ref SIZE windowSize,
    [In] ref UInt32 flags,
    [In,Optional] ref RECT excludeRect,
    [Out] out SIZE popupWindowPosition
);
```

I also implemented the `RECT`, `POINT` and `SIZE` structures and initialized them. Finally I called the function like so.

```
CalculatePopupWindowPosition(ref nIconPos, ref windowSize, ref flags, ref nIconRect, out windowSize);
```

This doesn't seem to work though, windowSize contains nothing but zeros, which it shouldn't. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I already tried that actually, didn't find it there and therefore tried to import it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flags` parameter needs to be passed by value rather than by reference:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CalculatePopupWindowPosition
(
    ref POINT anchorPoint,
    ref SIZE windowSize,
    uint flags,
    ref RECT excludeRect,
    out RECT popupWindowPosition
);
```

Some general advice. When an API call fails, check the return value. In this case if the function returns false then call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to find out the error status code.

Comment: Didn't notice for some reason that flags wasn't passed as a pointer in the syntax on MSDN.